# How to change border color of default custom dialog box?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator

How to change border color of default custom dialog box?Please Help me for this.Thank You.

Comment: Full documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `TelephonyManager.getPhoneType()`:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();

// test if phoneType is PHONE_TYPE_GSM or PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
```

Comment: No i dont want this.I want to display Radio frequency of cell phone in MHz.How to do this.Help me for this.Thank You.